# How to Change WooCommerce new order email?

Tags: email

I'm new to WooCommerce and I have had a request to make a minor change to
the new order email which I have managed to find the template, but I am not sure which line I should change.

At the moment the new order email has:

> You have received an order from (billing address first name)

But I want to change it to:

> You have received an order from (username which made the order)

Is this possible? Would this just change the variable the email is using?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the line I need to edit I think

```
<p><?php printf( __( 'You have received an order from %s. The order is as follows:', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_billing_full_name() ); ?></p>
```

would that change to

```
<p><?php printf( __( 'You have received an order from %s. The order is as follows:', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_user() ); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

Copy the email folder from the plugin directory to a woocommerce folder in your child-theme.

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/template/emails/admin-new-order.php
```

gets copied to

```
/wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php
```

Then you can change the email template to suit your needs.